# Cannot find module 'chalk'

Tags: python, reactjs, docker, react-hooks, chalk

Im building  with Docker-Compose a web app with Django backend and React frontend. All the code was given to me, cause its an exercise for a Trainee DevOps interview, so i only have to make the building and deploy.

The docker-compose build runs fine, but when i make the docker-compose up, i get the next error:

```
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  | > frontendpublic@0.1.0 start
frontend_1  | > node scripts/start.js
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
frontend_1  |   throw err;
frontend_1  |   ^
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  | Error: Cannot find module 'chalk'
frontend_1  | Require stack:
frontend_1  | - /frontend/scripts/start.js
frontend_1  |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
frontend_1  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
frontend_1  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
frontend_1  |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
frontend_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/frontend/scripts/start.js:18:15)
frontend_1  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
frontend_1  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
frontend_1  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
frontend_1  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
frontend_1  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12) {
frontend_1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
frontend_1  |   requireStack: [ '/frontend/scripts/start.js' ]
frontend_1  | }
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  | Node.js v19.3.0
```

The start.js script is using functions from the chalk module, but i dont know how to install it. Can you help me?

*START.JS:
*

```
'use strict';

// Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

// Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
// ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
// terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  throw err;
});

// Ensure environment variables are read.
require('../config/env');

const fs = require('fs');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const clearConsole = require('react-dev-utils/clearConsole');
const checkRequiredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/checkRequiredFiles');
const {
  choosePort,
  createCompiler,
  prepareProxy,
  prepareUrls,
} = require('react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils');
const openBrowser = require('react-dev-utils/openBrowser');
const paths = require('../config/paths');
const config = require('../config/webpack.config.dev');
const createDevServerConfig = require('../config/webpackDevServer.config');

const useYarn = fs.existsSync(paths.yarnLockFile);
const isInteractive = process.stdout.isTTY;

// Warn and crash if required files are missing
if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appHtml, paths.appIndexJs])) {
  process.exit(1);
}

// Tools like Cloud9 rely on this.
const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';

if (process.env.HOST) {
  console.log(
    chalk.cyan(
      `Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: ${chalk.yellow(
        chalk.bold(process.env.HOST)
      )}`
    )
  );
  console.log(
    `If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.`
  );
  console.log(`Learn more here: ${chalk.yellow('...')}`);
  console.log();
}

// We attempt to use the default port but if it is busy, we offer the user to
// run on a different port. `choosePort()` Promise resolves to the next free port.
choosePort(HOST, DEFAULT_PORT)
  .then(port => {
    if (port == null) {
      // We have not found a port.
      return;
    }
    const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http';
    const appName = require(paths.appPackageJson).name;
    const urls = prepareUrls(protocol, HOST, port);
    // Create a webpack compiler that is configured with custom messages.
    const compiler = createCompiler(webpack, config, appName, urls, useYarn);
    // Load proxy config
    const proxySetting = require(paths.appPackageJson).proxy;
    const proxyConfig = prepareProxy(proxySetting, paths.appPublic);
    // Serve webpack assets generated by the compiler over a web sever.
    const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
      proxyConfig,
      urls.lanUrlForConfig
    );
    const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
    // Launch WebpackDevServer.
    devServer.listen(port, HOST, err => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      if (isInteractive) {
        clearConsole();
      }
      console.log(chalk.cyan('Starting the development server...\n'));
      openBrowser(urls.localUrlForBrowser);
    });

    ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach(function(sig) {
      process.on(sig, function() {
        devServer.close();
        process.exit();
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err && err.message) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Thanks!

I was trying to run the services with docker-compose, but i have an error with the chalk module who is needed in script/start.js

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!
Added chalk to devDependencies on the file package.json. It was only on Dependencies.